# How does the latest RiverPod generator in flutter integrate with MVC

Tags: flutter, dart, model-view-controller, riverpod

For example: I have A page, A controller, in A controller store a lot of data and update data methods (string Boolean model class, update string update model class to get data), such a structure with the latest syntax generator should be how to achieve

```
class AController extends GetxController {
  // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- > State & Controller
  static EngineerRepairController get to => Get.find();

  CallDetailModel callDetailData = CallDetailModel();
  List<FaultTypeListModel> faultTypeList = [];

  @override
  void onInit() async {
    super.onInit();
    handleGetCallDetail();
  }

  // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- > Updater
  void updateCallDetail(CallDetailModel val) => callDetailData = val;
  void updateFaultType(List<FaultTypeListModel> val) => faultTypeList = val;

  // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- > Action
  Future handleGetCallDetail() async {
    try {
      Map<String, dynamic> params = {'id': Get.arguments['id']};
      dynamic res = await HttpService.to.get(EngineerRepairApis.getCallDetailDataApi, params: params);
      updateCallDetail(CallDetailModel.fromJson(res));
      update();
    } catch (e) {
    }
  }}

This is how I define and update data in getx. Now I'm trying to switch to riverpod. How do I implement this in the latest riverpod generator
```

Comment: Is this a "GetX" question but marked riverpod instead accidentally?

Comment: No, I was thinking about the getx implementation. How should I implement it with riverpod

Comment: There's a lot of riverpod docs.  In particular, check out these articles: Andrea Bizzotto's excellent collection of Riverpod tutorials: https://codewithandrea.com/tags/riverpod/